# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' Xml based

Tags: xml, hibernate, spring-mvc

Web.xml after hiting url localhost:8888/test.htm i got no mapping error so tell me where i did wrong? In my project i want to used Anotation and xml based..i done anotation based but for xml based no working.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

        <filter>
            <filter-name>GoogleSecurityFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>packagepath.filter.NameSpaceGoogleSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>GoogleSecurityFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>NewMarketPlaceApp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>packgepath.oauth2.NewMarketPlaceAppServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>NewMarketPlaceApp</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/newmarketplaceapp</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>CalendarAppEngineSample</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>packagepath.oauth2.CalendarAppEngineSample</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CalendarAppEngineSample</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/calendarAppEngineSample</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>CalendarAppEngineCallbackSample</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>packgepath.oauth2.CalendarAppEngineCallbackSample</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CalendarAppEngineCallbackSample</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/oauth2callback</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.bin</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping> 
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- <security-constraint>
           <web-resource-collection>
               <web-resource-name>cron</web-resource-name>
               <url-pattern>/cron/*</url-pattern>
           </web-resource-collection>
           <auth-constraint>
               <role-name>admin</role-name>
           </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint> -->


        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name/>
                <url-pattern>/calendarAppEngineSample</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>*</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <error-page>
            <exception-type>com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError</exception-type>
            <location>/errors/HardDeadlineExceededError.jsp</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>500</error-code>
            <location>/errors/servererror.jsp</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
            <exception-type>java.lang.Exception </exception-type>
            <location>/errors/nullPointerPage.jsp </location>
       </error-page>


        <!-- <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>calendarAppEngineSample</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list> -->
    <!--    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>gDirectory/login.htm</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>  -->

    </web-app>
```

Mvc-Dispatcher-Servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="path.*" />
    <context:annotation-config /> 
<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
<!--      <bean id="oauthSigner" class="com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthSigner"/>
     <bean id="contactsService" class="com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService"> 
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>Profile Directory</value>
        </constructor-arg>
     </bean>-->

     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:placeholder.properties"/>
     <!--   Start Interalization  -->
     <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="language" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
     <!--  End Interalization    -->

    <!-- Register the welcome.properties -->

   <bean name="/test.htm" 
    class="com.test.testapp.android.ExtensionController" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="Hibernate.xml"/> 

</beans>
```

Controller

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class ExtensionController extends AbstractController{

    /*@RequestMapping(value="/test.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getUserNames(HttpServletRequest req,@RequestParam String domainName) {


        return "helloWold";
    }*/

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove handler mapping bean inside your spring configuration. In current configuration you specified `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` so by default it checks for the @RequestMapping annotation. If you don't want to use @RequestMapping annotation,just remove your handler mapping bean, so by default it takes BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.